# Mapping axios response (array of arrays) to typescript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm using an API that returns the following response:

```
[
  [ 1636765200000, 254.46, 248.07, 254.78, 248.05, 2074.9316693 ],
  [ 1636761600000, 251.14, 254.29, 255.73, 251.14, 5965.53873045 ],
  [ 1636758000000, 251.25, 251.15, 252.97, 249.78, 7803.5565834 ],
  ... more items
]
```

I use axios to make a request against it as follows:

```
let res = await axios.get<CandlesResponse[]>(`${baseUrl}/${pathParams}?${queryParams}`);
let {data} = res;
```

In this case, TS infers the following:

- let res: AxiosResponse<CandlesResponse[], any>
- let data: CandlesResponse[]

I'm having troubles understanding how to define the interface that gets mapped.
I tried the following:

```
interface CandlesResponse {
    values:number[];
}
```

If I run, for example:

```
let lastCandle = data[119];
console.log(lastCandle.values)
```

in both cases, I got *undefined* as response.

While trying I managed to find something that works defining the Interface as follows:

```
interface CandlesResponse {
    0:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
    1:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
    2:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
    3:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
    4:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
    5:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
}
```

But I cannot understand why it works.
I also found out (and this, to me, makes more sense since each CandlesResponse is an array of numbers) that it works also defining the interface like this:

```
interface CandlesResponse {
    0:number;
    1:number;
    2:number;
    3:number;
    4:number;
    5:number;
}
```

This allows me to get the values like this:

```
let lastCandle = data[119];
console.log(lastCandle[0])
```

obtaining 1636340400000.

I need to understand why does it work like this. In particular, why does it work in both ways:

- 0:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
- 0:number;

Why the values:number[]; approach returns undefined, instead?

Also I want to understand if there is the possibility to give a proper name, instead of an index, to access those values. I want something that looks like this:

```
interface CandlesResponse {
    MTS:number;
    OPEN:number;
    CLOSE:number;
    HIGH:number;
    LOW:number;
    VOLUME:number;
}

...

let lastCandle = data[119];
console.log(lastCandle.MTS);
```

I guess I'm a bit confused and I hope someone can help me understand the problem

EDIT:
I can obtain the structure that I want by doing something as follows:

```
interface CandlesResponse {
    0:number;
    1:number;
    2:number;
    3:number;
    4:number;
    5:number;
}

class Candle{
    MTS:number;
    OPEN:number;
    CLOSE:number;
    HIGH:number;
    LOW:number;
    VOLUME:number;

    constructor(MTS: number, OPEN: number, CLOSE: number, HIGH: number, LOW: number, VOLUME: number){
        this.MTS = MTS;
        this.OPEN = OPEN;
        this.CLOSE = CLOSE;
        this.HIGH = HIGH;
        this.LOW = LOW;
        this.VOLUME = VOLUME;
    }
}

...

    let res = await axios.get<CandlesResponse[]>(`${baseUrl}/${pathParams}?${queryParams}`);
    let {data} = res;
    let candles:Candle[] = data.map(candle => new Candle(candle[0], candle[1], candle[2], candle[3], candle[4], candle[5]))
    console.log(candles[1].CLOSE)
```

Still I cant understand why it worked defining in the CandlesResponse interface the properties like this:

```
0:[number, number, number, number, number, number];
```

I also wonder if there is a better way to do it

SUMMARY:

I want to understand if there is a way to map the response object by giving proper names to access the fields (response is an array of arrays and I want o give to each internal array's value a proper name instead of an index). Also I would like to understand how does it work

Comment: Could you please summarize the questions at the end? BTW, I would recommend using `[number, number, number, number, number][]` as the type and using a JSDoc comment to annotate it.

Comment: @Shivam I did a brief summary of my question. So you suggest me to map the data in a matrix shape (which is fine).. Is there a way to give to each internal array a proper name? Or can I access it only by using the index? 

What I'm asking if I can do something like: data[0][MTS] instead of data[0][0]

Comment: If you want to give the indices a name, then you'll probably have to do a runtime mapping between an array and an object with fields. It's unfortunate, but it's rare enough that this would be a performance concern.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is dealing with an interface that represents an array which basically has an auto incrementing key (or index).

If you create a dedicated type that represents a single Candle, and then use that to represent the shape of the response, it becomes a little easier. All you have to add is `[index: number]' to represent the index and it should work:

```
// Named this way to avoid clash with the existing Candle class
type CandleType = [number, number, number, number, number, number];

interface CandlesResponse {
    [key: number]: CandleType
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your explanation: 

 let res = await axios.get<CandlesResponse[]>(
    `${baseUrl}/${pathParams}?${queryParams}`
  );
  let { data } = res;

  console.log(data[1][0])

this allows me to access the data in a "matrix shape" (data[0][0]) and I think its great! I still can't understand also why this mapping ([key: number]) works. 
Is there a way, then, to give to every element of CandleType a name? For example to access it like this: data[0][MTT] ? 

Also can you explain me how the [key: number]: CandleType works?

Comment: Does [key: number]: CandleType means that i have a key that is a number (data[0]) that returns me a Candle Type which is an array of 5 numbers, right?
I

Comment: Yes, so if you were to assign a string as the key instead of a number, you would do `[key: string]`. The `key` part is just the name, so you can call this whatever you like.

Comment: I have a problem using this implementation: data[1][0] is a number, but of type CandleType. Why is that? Shouldn't I be able to assign it to a number variable?

Comment: I found a solution: I don't need CandleType. I can do the following:
interface CandlesResponse {
    [key: number]: number
}.
This should map the numbers of the internal array. I need to define, as generic type for axios' response CandlesResponse[]. By doing so I'm able to map them using the Candle class that I have posted in the question.

Comment: Ah ok I see. A small suggestion would be to have the `CandlesResponse` be responsible for the entire response rather than relying on having to define it as `CandlesResponse[]`. Elsewhere in your code you'll see `CandlesResponse` and think that is the actual response, whereas it is only one part of it. `CandlesResponse[]` to me says it's an array of responses.

Comment: I second that, so I chose this as implementation: 
interface CandleType {
  [key: number]: number;
} 

type CandlesResponse = CandleType[];

And this keeps working as desired ! Thank you for your help!